# Prevent elasticsearch to search witin specific fields

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

A program we're building uses elasticsearch as a search engine. In our program we have a role based access permissions system, that allows some users to see certain fields while other users can't see them. For instance, all users can see first- and last name and telephone number, but only the administrator can see the bank account details. Now, i want to be able to let an administrator search for "1234" and find all documents with a phonenumber or bank account containing "1234", but normal users should only be allowed to search within phonenumber. How can i do this?

Ideally, what i'd want is to include something like this (for users) in my query:

```
"fields_to_search": {
   { "firstname", "lastname", "telephone" }
}
"query" {
   "wildcard": {
      "_all" : "*1234*"
   }
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Suggestions i've seen before:
 - I can change the setting include_in_all, but then administrators also can't search in bankaccount using "_all" anymore;
 - I know i can use "fields" to specify wich fields to return, but i don't want bankaccount to be searched (by a user);
 - I can change the settings for "source", but that doesn't change which fields are being searched.
- Multi_match; the problem here is that this only works as a matchquery, while i also need to exclude the field "bankaccount" to be used in filters, wildcards, ranges, etc.,

Note: The example i give here is very simplified; in reality, there are more roles than only "users" and "administrators", and lots more than four fields: I need a flexible solution in which i can change the fields to be searched on the fly.

Comment: Auth stuff is something that should be done on the application side.

Comment: I know, and this has been delt with in the application. My question is: how can i prevent elasticsearch from searching in fields a user doesn't have permissions on?

Comment: If you're storing bank account numbers in clear text, you have bigger issues.